# In Flutter, how do I eliminate or minimize the vertical distance between two rows?

Tags: flutter

Here's a basic code which displays a Row containing IconButton's followed by a Row containing Text widgets:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AudioPlayerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String audioUrl;

  AudioPlayerScreen({required this.audioUrl});

  final double _audioIconSizeSmaller = 50;

  final double _audioIconSizeMedium = 60;

  final double _audioIconSizeLarge = 90;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Audio Player'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          _buildPositionButtons(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPositionButtons() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: IconButton(
                iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                onPressed: () => print(''),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: IconButton(
                iconSize: _audioIconSizeSmaller,
                onPressed: () => print(''),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: IconButton(
                iconSize: _audioIconSizeSmaller,
                onPressed: () => print(''),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: IconButton(
                iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                onPressed: () => print(''),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '1 m',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '10 s',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '10 s',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '1 m',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: AudioPlayerScreen(
      audioUrl: 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3',
    ),
  ));
}
```

The  result is:

[image]

Comment: Extra space is from padding of IconButton. Set padding to 0 to IconButtons.

Answer (score 0):

`Expanded` widget divided the space equally.

```
  Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
            onPressed: () => print(''),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: _audioIconSizeSmaller,
            onPressed: () => print(''),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: _audioIconSizeSmaller,
            onPressed: () => print(''),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
            onPressed: () => print(''),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

try to remove the `Expanded` widget and try `spaceAround` or `spaceEvenly` for mainAxisAlignment or you can use `Padding` or use `Flex` inside `Expanded` widget to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**You can wrap `Row` With Container Widget and set the size According:**

**Example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AudioPlayerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String audioUrl;

  AudioPlayerScreen({required this.audioUrl});

  final double _audioIconSizeSmaller = 50;

  final double _audioIconSizeMedium = 60;

  final double _audioIconSizeLarge = 90;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Audio Player'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          _buildPositionButtons(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPositionButtons() {
    return IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeSmaller,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeSmaller,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            height: 10.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    '1 m',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    '10 s',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    '10 s',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    '1 m',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the previous answers to reach my objective of reducing the vertical distance between the 2 rows. My solution is to include the first row which contains the icons into a SizedBox which reduces the row height as well as unify the size of the icons.

Here's the modified code:

```
  Widget _buildPositionButtons() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: _audioIconSizeMedium - 7,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: _audioIconSizeMedium,
                  onPressed: () => print(''),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '1 m',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '10 s',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '10 s',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '1 m',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Result:

[image]